# This is undefined after few iterations inside render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

The state has an array series and used using map inside render. After few iteration the local scope of this object shows undefined, but closure (render) shows the contents of this object.What could be the reason?

```js
render () {
     console.log("funding rounds",this)
     return (
       <div>
           {this.state.series
           ?
             this.state.series.map(item, index => {
               return(
                 <Series showEdit={item.showEdit?item.showEdit:false} data={item} index={index} accessor={this.props.accessor} isLocked={item.is_locked} params={this.props.params}/>
             )
           })
          :null
         }
       </div>
     );
   }
```

Comment: @Andrew Using the arrow notation of ES6 , binding is not necessary.

Comment: Event they have mentioned you can use like this if you are using ES6 notation list.map((item, i) => this.renderListItem(item, i))} which we are  already using it.

Comment: You are missing the surrounding `()` in the map arguments /try `this.state.series.map((item, index) => {`